# Flatten a multi-dimensional array of children, but keep dependency array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, flatten

I am trying to create a flatten array of a result I get from an API. The result array looks like this:

```
$arrayIhave = array(
 'element name single' => array(
   '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
   'id' => '1',
 ),
 'element name single2' => array(
   '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
   'id' => '2',
 ),
 'element name with nested' => array(
   '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
   'sub folder name' -> array(
     '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
     'id' => '3',
   ),
   'another sub folder' => array(
     '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
     'id' => '4',
   )
 ),
 'element name with multi nested' => array(
   '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
   'sub folder name' -> array(
     '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
        'sub sub folder name' -> array(
          '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
          'id' => '5',
        ),
     ),
   ),
   'another sub folder' => array(
     '__sort_name' => 'Name for sorting',
     'id' => '6',
   )
 ),
);
```

The final array, I'm trying to arrange has a each element id, and it's given dependencies in the tree. So a top level item has `id` dependencies for all it's sub-folders, no matter how many levels down.

The last sub-folder in the tree has dependency only for it's children. The dependency tree wouldn't use the id as `folders` don't have that.

Resulting array:

```
$arrayITryToHave = array(
 'element name single' => array(),
 'element name single2' => array(),
 'element name with nested' => array(
   'sub folder name',
 ),
 'element name with multi nested' => array(
   'sub folder name',
   'sub sub folder name', // Note the dependency array is flat and has all levels flatten
   'another sub folder',
 ),
 'sub folder name' => array( // Even though a subfolder, it has dependencies too
   'sub sub folder name',
 ),
);
```

I tried using `array_walk_recursive` and with `foreach` and `array_column` but that doesn't work on multi levels. I also tried with regular foreach and `&$reference` arrays, but I then fail to add the `sub sub folder` to a dependency 1 level above, and to a dependency another level above.

Code used so far:

```
function generateArray(&$array, $iterate){
      foreach($iterate as $key => $value){
        $id = $key;
        // Remove invalid elements
        if(isset($value['__sort_name'])) unset($value['__sort_name']);
        // If not present already, make an array
        if(!isset($array[$id])){
          $array[$id] = array();
        }
        array_push($array[$id], array_column($value, 'name', 'name'));
      }
    }
```

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To increase the chances of your question being answered, I would recommend including the code you've used in your solution attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Das_Geek, just did that!

Comment: In your output, why does `element name with nested` do not have ` another sub folder` ? Also your `$arrayIhave` is not having correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've managed to solve it this way, if anybody has a better way, please do let me know :)

```
function generateCollapseFolder($returnArr){
      $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
          new \RecursiveArrayIterator($returnArr),
          \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
      );
      $filtered = array();
      $filteredLastArrayHelper = array();
      foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
        // Get if we are deep down
        $currentDepth = $iterator->getDepth();
        $isNested = $currentDepth > 0;
        // We only care about this field
        if($key === '__sort_name'){
          if(!isset($filtered[$item])) $filtered[$item] = array();
          // Remember last level with key to match
          $filteredLastArrayHelper[$currentDepth] = $item;
          if($isNested){
            for ($x = $currentDepth - 1; $x >= 0; $x--) {
              $insertKey = $filteredLastArrayHelper[$x];
              if($insertKey){
                array_push($filtered[$insertKey], $item);
              }
            } 
          } else {
            // Reset the array
            $filteredLastArrayHelper = array();
          }
        }
      }
      return $filtered;
}
```